# FormGroup.patchValue keep disabled state of child controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive `FormGroup` instance with disabled form controls.
A valueChanges listener on one of the form controls sets other controls `disabled`.

Everytime I save the form's value to the backend, an updated object is returned and patched back into the form using `patchValue`.
Unfortunately, after patching the new object from the backend into the form group, the disabled state of all controls is lost.

1. I create the FormGroup on init
2. The user inputs some values (e.g. a URL) that causes other form controls to become disabled.
3. I save the value of the form
4. I receive an updated object from the Backend
5. I patch the updated object into the form.
6. Previously disabled form controls become enabled again.

How do I keep the disabled state of form controls after using `patchValue`?

Comment: What would be the flag for you to know (or for the Backend to know) which control should be disabled?

Comment: The controls are already disabled before saving (and thus patching). I just want the controls to stay disabled.

Comment: If you submit `form.value`, `disabled` controls will be disappeared from the form completely. You need to have some kind of flag (can be as simple as does the property for the corresponding control have value or not) to check when you build the form using `Form Builder`

Comment: I build the FormGroup only once at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a (dirty) workaround.

I added `.debounceTime(0)` before the `.subscribe` block and after I patch a new value into the form, the checkboxes are for a brief moment enabled, but get immediately disabled again.